# When checkout button is clicked, the login popup shows up how to disable this login form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, learnpress

I am using learnpress theme when I clicked checkout the login window popups

I need the user to be redirected to the cart or checkout page and not ask him to login or create an account.

Currently if you click on any of the TAKE THIS COURSE buttons, the login popup is triggered and you are forced to login or create an account to proceed.

I have already tried WooCommerce setting guest checkout but it's not working.

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Note that StackOverFlow is coding oriented and your question is related to Woocommerce settings. So try to read [the official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/woocommerce/info). The related Woocommerce settings are under "Accounts & Privacy" section.

Comment: Thats some settings of your theme or some plugin you use. If it's from theme, then you will have options to change that in theme customize